# Fullcalendar - display range event individually

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, fullcalendar

I'm using fullCalendar 3.10, I have events like following:

```
        $event_list[] = Calendar::event(
            $event->name,
            false,
            new \DateTime($event->start_date.' '.$event->start_time),
            new \DateTime($event->end_date.' '.$event->end_time),
            $event->id,
            [
                'color' => '#f05050',
                'slug' => $event->slug,
                'url' => 'event/'.$event->slug,
            ]
        );
```

Now let's say an event is within the date range 01.04.2019 to 04.04.2019, how do I show this as an individual event block instead of stretched event block on the month view? Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by this? You mean the event to be separate on each day, or what? Your description is not very precise

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple solution for you:

```
$event_list[] = Calendar::event(
            $event->name,
            false,
            new \DateTime($event->start_date.' '.$event->start_time),
            new \DateTime($event->end_date.' '.$event->end_time),
            rendering: 'background',
            backgroundColor = '#f05050',
            $event->id,
            [
               // 'color' => '#f05050',
                'slug' => $event->slug,
                'url' => 'event/'.$event->slug,
            ]
        );
```